# How to refer a cell to another cell in a statement using EXCEL

Tags: excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2auO.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjoAU.png)I want the values from cell C1 to the CELL F1. But the thing is, I want to insert them inside a statement like query ( INSIDE THE BRACKETS ) .

query : select * from volume_issue_info where job_id in ( ##I WANT TO PLACE HERE## ) and volume in () and issue in ()

I Tried the "=C1". It worth only when without the query statement.

select * from volume_issue_info where job_id in () and volume in () and issue in ()

advice me..!

Comment: The SQL `IN` clause is usually used with a CSV list of several values.  Please add enough data to your question to make it clear what query you are trying to build here.

Comment: Your link does not help at all.

Comment: Am just using for pasting in my DB editor. So, I need it to be merged for several entries.

Comment: Did this work for you?  If so, mind accepting the answer?  If not, happy to revise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

Using this updated [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjoAU.png) as a reference, I'm assuming that your first 3 fields are job_id in A1, volume in B1, and issue in C1.

I'm modifying my answer below to reference those cells.

I've done something similar in Excel before--building a query based on various data--and did it as follows:

Generally speaking, manipulating text in Excel requires you to have a function that works on 1 (or more) cells and puts a value into a cell.  (Yes, you can have array formulas and other complex multi-cell manipulation but I don't think that's needed here.)

Do these steps for the first row:

1. Add the text: "select * from volume_issue_info where job_id in (" in
   D1
2. Add the text: ") and volume in (" in E1
3. Add the text: ") and issue in (" in F1
4. Add the text: ")" in G1
5. Put the following formula in H1:  =concatenate(d1, a1, e1, b1, f1, c1, g1)
6. Copy & paste the formula in H1 down into other rows as needed.

Alternatively, and it's a bit more messy, you could put the following into D1:

```
="select * from volume_issue_info where job_id in ("&A1&") and volume in ("&B1&") and issue in ("&C1&")"
```

The & is a short hand for string concatenation.  This method is a bit more prone to potential typographical errors.

That should do it.

Comment: Updated another image. If I capture the required id in the () . I will copy all query at a time run through my DB software.  FYI

Comment: Gave 2 approaches to solve using the newest image as a data reference.

Comment: @Anguramangii you're welcome.  If you have a chance, would you mind clicking the checkmark that acknowledges the answer.  It'll give me some more rep.  :-)

Comment: Hey There..! checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55114430/10833898